# How to open Model file for OpenCV's structured edge detector in a DLL for LabVIEW?

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, visual-studio-2015, labview

I've created the EdgeBoxes.cpp Example DLL for LabVIEW using OpenCV. I'm trying to open the model file in the DLL but all I get is an assertion fail. I also created VI's for morphology, Corner detection, hough transformation but never got any error messages like that.

I tried:

- Every path combination using Forward slashes or back slashes.
- Putting every file into the same Folder(also in `C:\`). (LabVIEW VI, DLL, ModelFile)
- To open it in LabVIEW first with "`Open/Create/Replace.vi`"
- To open the extracted model.yml file instead of model.yml.gz
- Converting the yml file to json, txt doesn't work either

That's the point where I'm clueless:

```
string filename = "C:\model.yml.gz"
Ptr<StructuredEdgeDetection> pDollar; = createStructuredEdgeDetection(filename);
```

Error Message I'm receiving:

> Error -1002 occurred at OpenCV(4.0.1-dev)
>   C:\OpenCV\opencv_contrib-master\modules\ximgproc\src\structured_edge_detection.cpp:432:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) modelFile.isOpened() in function
>   'cv::ximgproc::StructuredEdgeDetectionImpl::StructuredEdgeDetectionImpl'

I don't know how to open this file without getting this error message. Is it even possible to access a file  in a DLL call. Do I have to open it somehow in the LabVIEW VI because of permission issues?
Thanks!

**Update: 1**

Now I tried to read the file with ifstream and it seems like I can acess the file without any Problems (Code below). So the reason why it won't work seems to be in context with OpenCV?

```
std::ifstream is(filename, std::ifstream::binary);

is.seekg(0, is.end);
int length = is.tellg();
is.seekg(0, is.beg);

char * buffer = new char[length];

is.read(buffer, length);
is.close();
delete[] buffer;    // buffer contains the entire file
```

**Update: 2**

Now I tried to open the file like OpenCV does after calling:

```
createStructuredEdgeDetection(filename);
```

After that OpenCV tries to open the file with:
See Row 431
https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/ximgproc/src/structured_edge_detection.cpp

```
cv::FileStorage modelFile(filename, FileStorage::READ);
if (modelFile.isOpened()) 
{ return -1; }
```

Why does it work with

```
ifstream::binary
```

Do I have to recompile the "structured_edge_detection.cpp"?

Comment: By the file extension, it appears that the file you are specifying is compressed or contained inside an archive (model.yml.gz). The function may be trying to load the file directly and cannot detect the contents as a yml file. Extract the file into the same folder and change your string assignment to " string filename = 'C:\model.yml' " and see if that helps. Found a similar question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49734695/structured-edge-detection

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried that too. Just forgot to mention it above. After extracting the file it's just a yml file --> model.yml. It doesn't work for any of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. All you need to do is to pay attention linking only the librarys with a "d" if you are using debug mode in Visual Studio. I was using both like:

```
opencv_imgproc401d.lib, opencv_imgproc401.lib, opencv.ximg....
```

After changing the additional linker dependencies only to the debug librarys

```
opencv_imgproc401d.lib;opencv_ximgproc401d.lib;opencv_core401d.lib;
```

everything worked fine for me.